# get html page after script execution via php

Tags: javascript, php, phantomjs

I did a lot of search... tried some methods..
There is  [webpage](http://sosyal.hurriyet.com.tr/yazar/niobe_141/seni-unutmuyoruz-pasam_40011882) that html contents come after script execution.

I used phantomJS with different method.

1-) ***Checking with document.ready***

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);
page.settings.userAgent = 'SpecialAgent';
page.open('http://sosyal.hurriyet.com.tr/yazar/niobe_141/seni-unutmuyoruz-pasam_40011882', function(status) {
 function checkReadyState() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var readyState = page.evaluate(function () {
                return document.readyState;
            });

            if ("complete" === readyState) {
                onPageReady();
            } else {
                checkReadyState();
            }
        });
    }

    checkReadyState();
});

function onPageReady() {
    var htmlContent = page.evaluate(function () {
       return document.body.textContent;
    });

    console.log(htmlContent);

    phantom.exit();
}
```

*Result:Script not loaded so unloaded html returned..*

2-)***Setting timeout too long***

```
  page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            var htmlContent = page.evaluate(function () {
       return document.getElementsByClassName('hsaalicc-text').textContent;
    });

    console.log(htmlContent);

        }, 1000); // Change timeout as required to allow sufficient time 
    }
});
```

*Result:Script not loaded so unloaded html returned..*

So although I'm android developper and have not too much jquery knowlodge looked page code with chrome developper console... And I see all data that should be load is in script with `window.articleDetailData`

[image]  Moreover I found the function that load data content.

```
('#templateArticleDetail').tmpl(data).appendTo('#articleDetailContainer');
```

There is no time parameter,but in mobile device it takes time. But in code I understand when page loaded it should copy to *#articleDetailContainer*

So my question
***1-)*** why document ready and high timeout not return loaded script page with phantomJS
***2-)*** Is there a way to parse windows.data under script tag??

If I could not find  any easy way,will use regex to parse script

Comment: So if a one second timeout did show the complete content, have you tried increasing the timeout? (trying to make sure it is loaded eventually) I don't know who introduced the `document.readyState` trick, but it has never worked in my experience.

Comment: used 10 sec-30 sec etc

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: latest one,2.0,and I dont think there is error...Because It print text which onloaded script... But in free time will test and return to you...

Comment: tested and giving Error code: 301. Description: Protocol "about" is unknown

Comment: I've never seen these error messages, but the page loads even without waiting. There is something missing, I guess it's comments and ads, but everything else seems to be there. I'm using PhantomJS 2.0.0 on windows. On PhantomJS 1.9.7 it's a little different where the page immediately after load is shown in mobile layout and a second after in desktop layout ([imgur](http://imgur.com/a/OTvty)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use PhantomJsCloud.com to do this, though in the answers below, I'll try to explain the process if you want to try to use your own phantomjs.exe instance.  (Disclosure: I wrote PhantomJsCloud)

Docs for PhantomJsCloud here: http://api.phantomjscloud.com/

1)  Waiting for AJAX?

**Using PhantomJsCloud:** Just a normal request, everything is automatically loaded properly.  Here is your page rendered as a PNG:  [http://api.phantomjscloud.com/api/browser/v2/a-demo-key-with-low-quota-per-ip-address/?request={url:%22http://sosyal.hurriyet.com.tr/yazar/niobe_141/seni-unutmuyoruz-pasam_40011882%22,renderType:%22png%22}](http://api.phantomjscloud.com/api/browser/v2/a-demo-key-with-low-quota-per-ip-address/?request=%7Burl:%22http://sosyal.hurriyet.com.tr/yazar/niobe_141/seni-unutmuyoruz-pasam_40011882%22,renderType:%22png%22%7D)

**Using PhantomJs.exe:** If you do it yourself, you need to make sure all ajax resource requests are complete before rendering.   (see the WebPage.OnResourceRecieved() api)

2) Parse windows.data?

**Using PhantomJsCloud:** Set pageRequest.requestType="script", Use pageRequest.scripts to execute your script, and return the data you want.  For example:  [http://api.phantomjscloud.com/api/browser/v2/a-demo-key-with-low-quota-per-ip-address/?request={url:%22http://example.com%22,renderType:%22script%22,scripts:{loadFinished:[%22return%20{hello:%27world%27,host:document.location.host};%22]}}](http://api.phantomjscloud.com/api/browser/v2/a-demo-key-with-low-quota-per-ip-address/?request=%7Burl:%22http://example.com%22,renderType:%22script%22,scripts:%7BloadFinished:[%22return%20%7Bhello:%27world%27,host:document.location.host%7D;%22]%7D%7D)

**Using PhantomJs.exe:** You need to use http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/include-js.html or injectJs and load a script that will do your parsing, and then send it back to your phantomjs.exe code via http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-callback.html

Comment: thanks for explanation and effort. As using PhantomJs since morning to evenning ,released that this executable library is too slow and before your comment tried reguler expression since  the webside have data on script file... and i got what ı want... Moreover,it is more speedy..